# What is the best practice for coding addChangeHandler in Gwt?

Tags: gwt

in UiBinder

```
@UiField ListBox testListBox;
```

in presenter, I have a method `getData()` that put data into the `testListBox`.

```
public void getData(){
        getView().getTestListBox().clear();
        getView().getTestListBox().addItem("itm 1");
        getView().getTestListBox().addItem("itm 2");
        getView().getTestListBox().addItem("itm 3");
        getView().getTestListBox().addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int ind=getView().getTestListBox().getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println(getView().getTestListBox().getValue(ind));
            }

        });
}
```

Now, i also have a button to call `getData()`. If i click that button 1 time, then I select "itm 1" in the `testListBox` everything is fine as it will print out:

```
itm 1
```

However, if I click that button 2nd times, & select "itm 1" then it prints out twice "itm 1":

```
itm 1
itm 1
```

If i click it 3rd time, it will print out triple "itm 1"....

But if i put the `getView().getTestListBox().addChangeHandler` outside `getData()` method before i add the item into the listbox (ie I do the `addChangeHandler` before there is actual item inside the listbox), then everything is fine as it print out only 1 time.

So What is the best practice for coding addChangeHandler in Gwt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing is that you call `addChangeHandler()` only once. If you call it multiple times (as in your scenario) you end up having multiple handlers all getting invoked at the same time when the value changes (hence the repeted values getting printed).

It doesn't really matter if you call `addChangeHandler()` before or after adding the actual items. I usually add the change handler right after creating the ListBox instance, and that's what I have seen done most often.

Since you are using UIBinder, the ListBox instance gets created automatically for you. In this case a good place to call `addChangeHandler()` would be in the UI container's constructor. When using MVP, it should probably go in the presenter's bind method.

Comment: yes, but sometimes items inside the list need to interact with other outside variable, so if putting in the View then u may need to bring outside variable over.

Comment: You're right, with MVP it should probably go in the presenter.